# Ag-grid create own custom message

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I would like to **create my own custom message/alert** and display it instead of rows with data in some specific situation. Right now we have in ag-grid 'loading' and 'no-rows-to-show' messages and we can customize them but I would like to create different kind of message which can inform user that we don't display data because some criteria hasn't been met. Is is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can defined your own template for no rows overlay and show it whenever needed.

For that, you need to update the `ag-grid-angular` markup with below attributes

```
[overlayLoadingTemplate]="overlayLoadingTemplate"
[overlayNoRowsTemplate]="overlayNoRowsTemplate"
```

And provide the template in the component as below

```
this.overlayLoadingTemplate =
  '<span class="ag-overlay-loading-center">Please wait while your rows are loading</span>';
this.overlayNoRowsTemplate =
  "<span style=\"padding: 10px; border: 2px solid #444; background: lightgoldenrodyellow;\">This is a custom 'no rows' overlay</span>";
```

You can provide the message in the template itself.

Here is [the example on ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlays/#example) .